# How to Pass-In the Credentials for me Read an Excel file from an Office 365 site that has 2nd layer of authentication which is ADFS

Tags: c#, excel, office365

I am trying to implement the following code but I am getting a 403 or Forbidden error. Obviously, I am not passing in the right credentials. How do I do that?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh124646(v=office.14).aspx

I'm not going to use CSOM.

There is also a 2-way authentication happening which is first, it authenticates the user to connect using O365 credentials and then ADFS.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are authorized to access the document, and also make sure that you are passing the right creds to SharePoint Api. Make sure that you are setting the right username and password in your request.

```
request.Credentials =
         System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Let me know how it goes. Hope this helps.